# Dex fails when using StreamSupport library

Tags: java, android, java-8, java-stream, dex

I'm trying to use [StreamSupport](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) to use certain Java 8 APIs. My application has a minSDK of `15` and a compileSDK of `25`

The exact error I'm getting is:

> Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljava8/util/CollSer

I do see `CollSer` defined in StreamSupport, but StreamSupport only shows up once in my dependency tree.

Comment: No way to help you in diagnosing that unless you show us at least your build.gradle ... Also: what's your Andoid Studio Version, Settings, JDK used, and so on ...

Comment: Do you have `streamsupport-literal` on your build path in addition to the main `streamsupport` (1.6.0 or 1.6.1) component? If yes, then please  remove the `streamsupport-literal` component and tell us what happens.

Comment: @StefanZobel I originally had literal along with `streamsupport` 1.6.0, switched to just `streamsupport` and still had the clash

Comment: Hhm ... Also cleaned / rebuilt the project from scratch? As a matter of fact, you don't need streamsupport-literal with 1.6.0 or 1.6.1. The API has moved to the main component in 1.6.0. Anyway, something seems to be fishy with your project setup. I never have any problems using all of the components together. What's your AS version?

Comment: Trying `streamsupport` with everything except `literal` worked after I undid adding multidex (an unrelated change). I had cleaned the project multiple times but I suspect there was something getting cached since `streamsupport` with just the core should have worked from what I can tell. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: I've never tried multidex with streamsupport (should work though). Some caching under the hood is a plausible explanation. Btw., if you have a need for the JEP269 Java 9 collection factory methods from `literal` - they are in the `Lists`, `Sets`, `Maps` companion classes now (in the main component).

Comment: @StefanZobel I was just looking through your Github repos and `retrostreams` actually looks like a much cleaner option. Would you consider it production ready? (no promises implied of course)

Comment: Yes, for Android Devs using the new Android Studio 3.x it is indeed the better choice. As for "production-ready": that depends only on the quality of the desugar (or its successor) toolchain used in AS. `android-retrostreams` is simply Java 8 bytecode, compiled with `javac`. The source is the same as in `streamsupport` with the exception, that I've reintroduced all default / static interface methods from Java 8/9 (that are in the public API). The test suite runs successfully against retrostreams on Android 6.0.1 and Oreo (~ 20000 tests).

Comment: I'd be interested if the problem reappears when you enable multidex again. In any case, having the same class in two different jars was an oversight. I've filed a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/streamsupport/tickets/356/) - it will be fixed in 1.6.2. The good news is that this cannot happen in android-retrostreams.

Comment: I'm using 1.6.0, and remove `literal` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing multidex, but I suspect the real cause was caching issues.

Comment: Leaving the question open in case anyone has other suggestions

Comment: I don't have this in my build.gradle file. Clean of the project didn't help either :/